# Pythons: input() not working in .exe?

Tags: python, input, exe, command-prompt

I recently converted a text-based adventure game to a .exe using PyInstaller for my friend to view it easily. But when I test the exe file myself, every time it comes across an 'input()', it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ADVENTURE.py", line 37, in <module>
    what_is_your_name = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Anyone know why this is? input() is a big part of my game and I would really appreciate it if there is any way to fix this. 
Thanks!

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? That may make a big difference.

Comment: If you're using python 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what happens with `input()` in Python 2. It looks like your PyInstaller is compiling the program with Python 2. You need to configure it to compile that program with Python 3.